How to fixed hacked wordpress site
So I have a wordpress site (sevenavedesign.com) and currently I'm having an issue where when visiting the site sometimes it redirects to a spamvertising site. This does not always happens and it happens more often when visiting the site with a mobile device. I did a clean install of all the wordpress core files/folders, I searched the database for any script tags and links. I also checked and cleaned the config file, but the issue is still present. Not sure what else to do. I installed wordfence plugin (free version) and fixed all the issues it found, but again the issue persists. Unfortunately I do not have a working backup of when this issue was not present.
I don't believe the whole server is compromised since all other sites (including some wordpress sites) are working fine.
I was wondering if anyone has any other suggestions since I'm not that familiar with wordpress.
Thanks
RAS

It can be a awordpress addon you have that is acting that way, it can be really a lot of causes. It's too broad for here
